# return redirect not working inside looping - face recognition

Tags: python

this is my code

```
for (x, y, w, h) in features:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
        id, pred = clf.predict(gray_image[y:y + h, x:x + w])
        confidence = int(100 * (1 - pred / 300))

        mycursor.execute("select b.prs_name "
                         "  from img_dataset a "
                         "  left join prs_mstr b on a.img_person = b.prs_nbr "
                         " where img_id = " + str(id))
        s = mycursor.fetchone()
        s = '' + ''.join(s)

        if confidence > 70:
            cv2.putText(img, s, (x, y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, color, 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            return redirect('https://www.example.com')  # Pastikan URL-nya benar


        else:
            cv2.putText(img, "UNKNOWN", (x, y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 0, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

        coords = [x, y, w, h]
    return coords
```

return redirect not working, somebody know why?
if i use print inside confidence >70, the print will working, but still return redirect not working

Comment: Due to indentation it's not clear what you want to get as a result. Use 'break' if you need just a very first 'coords' you get or convert your code into function and return every 'coords' with 'yield'

Comment: Because as it is - you can't use 'return' outside a function,